# Integral substition

Tags: calculus

$M_{2k} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-2}^{2}x^{2k}\sqrt{4-x^2}dx$

Let $x = \sin \theta$

$ M_{2k} = \frac{2}{\pi}\cdot2^{2k}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{2k}\theta \cos^2 \theta d \theta $

I do not understand how the 2nd integral is got to from the first, particularly as $\theta$  is undefined when $\sin(\theta) = 2$

Comment: Substitution should be $x = 2\sin \theta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution used is :  $$x=2 \sin \theta \implies dx=2 \cos \theta d \theta$$
And $ x=2 \implies \theta = \dfrac {\pi}2 ,x=-2 \implies \theta =- \dfrac {\pi}2$
$$I = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-2}^{2}x^{2k}\sqrt{4-x^2}dx$$
The integral becomes:
$$I= \frac{2^{2(k+1)}}{\pi}\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{2k}\theta \cos^2 \theta d \theta$$

Comment: I couldn't solve that DE, so I searched around for Differential Equations Books, and Calculus books to catch up in your answer which worked. Great answer. +1

Comment: Thank you @EnlightenedFunky  which DE ?

Comment: The one you solved in terms of y it involved $\tan(y)$, and it was in differential form.

Comment: Oh I see now which one...Yes that's an interesting DE @EnlightenedFunky

Comment: This gives $\frac{2^{2(k+1)}}{\pi}$ as the fraction but in http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~zeitouni/cupbook.pdf page 7 it is $\frac{2 \cdot 2k}{\pi}$  so out my a factor of 2

Comment: A factor 2 is coming from the $dx=2 \cos \theta $ the other one comes from the sqrt  @abcdez

Comment: I understand your answer but I don't understand why it is different from the one in the book unless the book is wrong

Comment: Check that sigma has a factor 2 at the denominator @abcdez

Comment: Yes you're right thank you

Comment: sigma is $\frac 1 {2 \pi } \sqrt {4-x^2}$ @abcdez

Comment: You're welcome @abcdez